# Java automatic HTTP headers on OutputStream

Tags: java, c#, sockets, http, server

I have a simple **Java** TCP Server application that listens for connections and one a client connects it sends a string. If I run the server and make a GET request from a browser the string sent by the server is displayed. This is great, but, How did it work without HTTP Headers? Is the **OutputStream** class prepending HTTP Headers?

When I write the same code in **C#**, it doesnt work without Headers, the browsers doesnt display the sent string if there no HTTP headers prepended. The C# behavoir makes sense, so, whats happening with my java code?

**Java code**

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
            System.out.println("Servidor iniciado.\naguardando a conexao de um cliente...");
            Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Um cliente conectou-se ao nosso servidor Socket TCP");



            OutputStream streamSaida = null;
            //Obter a referencia do stream de saida do cliente conectado.
            streamSaida = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

            String bemVindo = "Bem vindo ao nosso primeiro servidor";
            streamSaida.write(bemVindo.getBytes());

            System.out.println("Desligando o servidor");
            clientSocket.close();
            server.close();
```

**C# code**

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener server = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, 8080);
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Servidor TCP iniciado");
            Console.WriteLine("Aguardando conexao de um cliente...");
            Socket client = server.AcceptSocket();

            Console.WriteLine("Um cliente conectou-se ao servidor");

            String msg = "Bem-vindo ao nosso servidor TCP C#"; //Mensagem de boas vindas

            NetworkStream streamCliente = new NetworkStream(client);
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(streamCliente);
            writer.Write(msg);
            writer.Flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't prepend any headers when you use plain socekts, most browsers display the data you send to them as string if they are not other documents.
Maybe youd don't close the connection in C# version, so, broswer doesn't know when you finish transferring your data to it, and is waiting for the close of connection before interpretation of the data (displaying it in your case). Try to add call to close your connection at the end of your program, eg. client.Close();

Comment: Even closing the connection I keep having the same error when making request from browser : **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**. What now?